# Suggestions on dynamic textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i got this problem and i cant figure it out what to do, my suggestion box displays on the first input but when i add more textboxes it just display an error that i have on my autocomplete.php, im really new on jquery and scripts, i really dont know what to do

this is my html and JS for the suggestion box

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).on('click', '.service', function auto() {
    //Al escribr dentro del input con id="service"
    $('#service').keypress(function() {
      //Obtenemos el value del input
      var service = $(this).val();
      var dataString = 'service=' + service;

      //Le pasamos el valor del input al ajax
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "autocomplete.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
          //Escribimos las sugerencias que nos manda la consulta
          $('#suggestions').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
          //Al hacer click en algua de las sugerencias
          $('.suggest-element a').click(function() {
            //Obtenemos la id unica de la sugerencia pulsada
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            //Editamos el valor del input con data de la sugerencia pulsada
            $('#service').val($('#' + id).attr('data'));
            //Hacemos desaparecer el resto de sugerencias
            $('#suggestions').fadeOut(1000);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }); < /script>
```

```html
<td align="center">
  <input type="checkbox" value="X" name="articulo[]" id="articulo" />
</td>
<td>
  <input class="form-control" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" type="text" maxlength="5" size="5" value="">
</td>

<td align="center">
  <input type="text" size="50" id="service" class="auto" name="service[]" />
  <div id="suggestions"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="900" class="table table-bordered table-condensed" align="center">

  <div id="inputs"></div>
```

and i use this for the dynamic outputs

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var j = 1;
// Input adding function
function addInput() {
    $('#inputs').append(
      '<table width="900" class="table table-bordered table-condensed"  align="center"><tr>' +
      '<td width="20"align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="X" name="articulo[]" id="articulo' + j + '"/></td> ' +
      '<td width="95"> <input class="form-control"name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad' + j + '" type="text"  maxlength="5" size="5" value="" > </td>' +
      '<td width="100" align="center"><input type="text" size="50" id="service' + j + '" class="auto"name="service[]" /></td><div id="suggestions"></div> ' +
      '</tr></table>'
    );
    j++;
  }
  // Event handler and the first input
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#adder').click(addInput);
  addInput();
}); < /script>
```

i already tried to put the suggestion script inside the addinput function changing the selector but nothing also i already tried to change this line

```
$('.suggest-element a' ).click( function(){
```

for this one

```
$(‘#suggestions’).on(‘click’,’.suggest-element’, function(){
```

but nothing its been a week  already and im beginning to think that i should re-write the whole code :(
this is my autocomplete.php

```
if(isset($_POST['service'])) {
            $queryString = $_POST['service'];

        // Is the string length greater than 0?

        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
            countries it works like this...
             LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10
                            $query = new consulta("SELECT ALL CVE_ART, DESCR FROM INVE$empresa WHERE ((upper(DESCR COLLATE ES_ES_CI_AI )) LIKE '%$queryString%' OR CVE_ART LIKE '%$queryString%') AND STATUS = 'A' ORDER BY DESCR ASC, CVE_ART ASC");
                if($query) {
                // While there are results loop through them - fetching an Object (i like PHP5 btw!).
                do {
                    // Format the results, im using <li> for the list, you can change it.
                    // The onClick function fills the textbox with the result.
                    // YOU MUST CHANGE: $result->value to $result->your_colum
                    echo '<div class="suggest-element"><a class="service" data="'.$query->rows['DESCR'].'"id="service'.$query->rows['CVE_ART'].'">'.utf8_encode($query->rows['DESCR']).'</a></div>';
                }  while ($query->rows = $query->consulta_exec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

            } else {
                echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
            }
        } else {
            // Dont do anything.
        } // There is a queryString.
    } else {
        echo 'There should be no direct access to this scripts!';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the format of the data coming back from the ajax response? I would need to see what the element looks like that has the 'suggest-element' class

Comment: ok now i have my autocomplete.php  there is the suggest-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call your `addInput` function you append a new div:

```
<div id="suggestions"></div>
```

So you'll have multiple div's with the same id. By the time you call:

```
$('#suggestions').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
```

Only your first suggestion box will be populated with data. Try adding a class to this element and querying by class instead